# Multiple paired permutation t-tests using perm.t.test

Tags: r, dplyr, permutation, t-test

I have some data from an experiment to analyse with R but I have a problem and after days of search, I can't find a solution.

I need to run multiple paired permutation t-tests on my data. This is a reduced version of my dataset:

```
treat = c("C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C",
         "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","T","T","T","T","T","T",
         "T","T","T","T","T","T","T","T","T","T","T","T","T","T")
subj = c("B16","B17","B18","B19","B20","B16","B17","B18","B19",
        "B20","B16","B17","B18","B19","B20","B16","B17","B18",
        "B19","B20","B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B1","B2","B3","B4"
        ,"B5","B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B1","B2","B3","B4","B5")
t = c("T0","T0","T0","T0","T0","T1","T1","T1","T1","T1","T2",
      "T2","T2","T2","T2","T3","T3","T3","T3","T3","T0","T0",
      "T0","T0","T0","T1","T1","T1","T1","T1","T2","T2","T2",
      "T2","T2","T3","T3","T3","T3","T3")
exparat = c(0.11,0.27,0.04,0.47,-0.11,-0.05,-0.05,0.33,-0.11,
            0.47,-0.01,0.43,0.47,0.33,-0.11,-0.09,0.20,-0.11,
                0.47,0.33,0.19,0.02,0.33,0.47,-0.11,0.42,0.13,0.47,
                -0.11,0.33,0.42,0.19,-0.11,0.33,0.47,0.42,0.17,
                0.33,0.47,-0.11)

data = data.frame(treat, subj, t, exparat)

head(data)

  treat subj  t exparat
1     C  B16 T0    0.11
2     C  B17 T0    0.27
3     C  B18 T0    0.04
4     C  B19 T0    0.47
5     C  B20 T0   -0.11
6     C  B16 T1   -0.05
```

For examples, I have to say if there are differences in my response variable (respvar) between combinations of times (t) independently for each treatment (treat). If I had to use a parametric t-test I would have used a dplyr pipe and the function group_by:

```
stat.test <- data %>%
  group_by(treat) %>%
  t_test(exparat ~ t, paired = TRUE)
```

But I can't do the same thing for permutation t-tests (perm.t.test, package: RVAideMemoire), because it only allows tests for factors with two levels. While my factor time (t) has 4 levels. One solution would be to subset my data for each pair of time (t) like this:

```
perm.t.test(exparat~t,data = subset(data, t == "T1" | t == "T2"), nperm=999, paired = T)
perm.t.test(exparat~t,data = subset(data, t == "T1" | t == "T3"), nperm=999, paired = T)
perm.t.test(exparat~t,data = subset(data, t == "T2" | t == "T3"), nperm=999, paired = T)
perm.t.test(exparat~t,data = subset(data, t == "T1" | t == "T2"), nperm=999, paired = T)
perm.t.test(exparat~t,data = subset(data, t == "T1" | t == "T3"), nperm=999, paired = T)
perm.t.test(exparat~t,data = subset(data, t == "T2" | t == "T3"), nperm=999, paired = T)
    
#and so on
```

But it seems a very inefficient and time-consuming way to do it. And in my real dataset, I do have many more levels of the factor t, so it will take a very long time to set up all this.

Can anyone help me to set a loop for doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what t-tests exactly you want to perform?  A t-test compared only two groups, but you have 14 levels in your predictor variable. So what do you want to compare?

Comment: I would like to perform tests between times, for example T1 vs T2, T2 vs T3, T3 vs T4 and so on. I've modified the post to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combn` to get all the combinations of `data$t` value.

```
combn(levels(data$t), 2, function(x) {
  perm.t.test(exparat~t,data = subset(data, t %in% x), nperm=999, paired = T)
}, simplify = FALSE) -> result

result
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak, but it seems it doesn't work. I get this error:  "Error in perm.t.test.formula(exparat ~ t, data = subset(data, t %in% x),  : 
  t is not a 2-levels factor "

Comment: Hi Ronak, if it can help, I've modified the post and added the code to reproduce a reduced version of my dataset.

Comment: Hi Valerio, If I use the data provided by you with `data = data.frame(treat, subj, t, exparat, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)` and use `MKinfer::perm.t.test` I don't get any error. Have you tried the answer on the same data?

Comment: Thank you Ronak, that's true, it works with MKinfer::perm.t.test, I was using RVAideMemoire::perm.t.test and it was not working. But I still have two problems: one is that I don't know which test is which, because there is no mention in the results to the combinations of t. The second is that I would need a data.frame output, with each row containing a test. Do you think is possible?

Comment: I have asked another question for this in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67757653/transform-a-list-of-t-tests-results-into-a-data-frame . I would be really glad if you could help me.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your edit in the comment. I have added an answer there. Hope that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much Ronak! Just a last thing, in the function you gave me data are not grouped by treatment (treat). Is there a way to use combn on subsets of my data for the factor treat? Like a using both 'by(data, data$treat, function(sub)' and 'combn(levels(data$t), 2, function(x)'. Sorry I'm new to R, but I find these loops extremely useful and I would love to learn.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. I think you can try something like this - `by(data, data$treat, function(sub) combn(levels(sub$t), 2, function(x) {
  perm.t.test(exparat~t,data = subset(data, t %in% x), nperm=999, paired = T)
}, simplify = FALSE)) `